# How delay or phase shift a signal?

Tags: 555, phase-shift

I'm using a 555 to create a throbbing effect on a LED, like in [this project](http://www.instructables.com/id/ThrobbingFading-LED-with-555-Timer/).

Is there a simple way to delay the signal for a second (then third, then forth...) LED to have them fade in and out at different times?

**EDIT:** I appreciate the workaround suggestions, but I'm really interested in the original question:

*Is there a simple way to delay or phase shift the signal?*

Even "it's not possible" or "it's very complicated" are good answers.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so that circuit builds the common 555 square wave oscillator and drives an emitter follower from the capacitor voltage.  The emitter follower drives the LED.

To get the multi-stage throbing build first a circuit that produces multiple phase-shifted square waves - for example build a ring counter ans drive the clock input using the 555 - then smooth the edges of the pulses from the ring counter with the resistor-capacitor-transistor combination that the throbbing circuit uses.  Use a smaller resistor or capacitor on the 555 as it will need to run faster in this application.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you are trying to do, but take a look at [555 based knight rider circuit](http://www.555-timer-circuits.com/knight-rider.html) or [555 based police lights](http://www.555-timer-circuits.com/police-lights.html). I don't know what supplies are available, but to add throbbing to these designs you would need multiple 555s or something smarter I can't think of.